# How to resolve JAR mismatches in android ?

Tags: android, facebook, android-navigation, android-actionbaractivity

I have implemented facebook login in my android app.
Jar file required -

**android-support-v4.jar which is 342kb**

And have excuted android slide panel in a demo project from here

**http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/**
Jar file required for this-

**android-support-v4.jar which is 544kb**

Now this works like piece of cake seperately.
When i try to implement the slide panel stuff to my project with fb login
It strucks at

**private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;**
Drawer layout and ActionBar cannot be resolved.

Vice versa if i change the jars files then fb connect runs in errors.
Please explain how to sort this..........
Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two or more .jar files with the same name that have different contents in the same project. You will need to copy the same version of the .jar file to all `libs` folders where it is needed or add it as a project wide dependency.

In the case of `android-support-v4.jar` you can download the latest version via the SDK Manager and use that were needed.

Comment: I have updated android-support but issues still there one thing works other not :(

Comment: Have you made sure you have the same copy in all the `libs` folders in all libraries you are using? You literally have to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for this in eclipse

click properties on the project you are having issues with, and then check out the build path, also you will want to see if anything has a red x on it.  Another thing to try is to check out the android tab in project properties.  You usually have to link the library there at the bottom.